# Как узнать какие cookie нужны для сайта

Tags: curl, cookie

В браузере можно понять какие нужны куки для того, что бы быть авторизированным.

[image: Просмотр куков в браузере]

Написав скрипт авторизации через CURL, я могу авторизоваться и сохранить куки в файл и затем использовать его что бы быть авторизованным. Но проблема в том, что при повторном заходе через curl с отправкой тех же куков - сайт видит меня как гостя. То есть приходится постоянно проходить форму авторизации. Хотя такой же самый скрипт работает чётко на других сайтах.

Проблема именно с конкретным сайтом. Помогите разобраться почему этот сайт не пускает с теми же куками.

Comment: Наверное на сервере сессия пропадает после выхода с сайта.

Comment: @Sergey нет не пропадает, проверил